# Creating new Git branches all the time even for minor/trivial changes

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

For a big project (front-end for filters), I have been working on a branch called `filtersfrontend`. But then I need to apply very minor fixes such as moving a button a few pixels down or changing the padding of an element a little bit for a `<div>` or `<span>` element for something that has absolutely nothing to do with the front-end for filters project.

This question is not intended to generate debate and I hope it does not get closed as a result of not having a Yes/No answer. I am looking for a best practice. Should I create new branches with intuitive names for every minor/trivial change that is unrelated to my big project, or is it okay the way I have been doing it, keep working on my `filtersfrontend` branch for the big project and just add minor changes to it. Yes, the problem is that minor/trivial changes multiplied for several times can became several lines of code and if I decided to abandon that branch because the big project of the front-end for filters does not end up being released, I will need to search in the commits to rescue code about minor/trivial changes that I had included in that branch.

Hopefully you can share with me if there is a best practice about this and this question does not get closed by administrators.

Comment: There is no good or bad answer. Best practices are set by the team and project demands. There people who work only on `master`, there are people who makes `branches`, there are people who use `git-flow`. There is an old arguably well explaining article on `branching` https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. However, again it is all matter of setting up your practices. Just remember, that there is always a `merge` in the end of the day.

Comment: For your case, if change does not fit the scope of current branch, you probably could create another branch, commit it, merge it to master, then sync master with previous branch, then finish it, commit it and merge to the master. So I think question will be a flame of holy wars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of creating separate branches for minor changes related to the work you are doing on a long-running branch... Unless you want to keep those minor changes as "merges" and not just fast-forwards on a linear branch when you merge them into the original long-running branch.... But, hey... that's a mater of taste, if you ask me. I would rather worry about the question of "when do I delete those minor-change branches? Do I keep them for long?" And then my answer would be "what's the point of keeping them?".

Comment: Me neither. I do not see the point of creating separate branches for minor changes related to the work that I am doing on a long-running branch. The point here is that the minor changes are UNRELATED TO THE WORK. As I mentioned, maybe some margin or padding in the footer that has nothing to do with the current long-running branch that I am using.

Comment: **No need to yell at me**

Comment: I am sorry for using capital letters, I should have used bold instead, or quotes. I was just trying to emphasize that part and I never meant to be mean. It is the opposite, thank you for providing an answer to my question.

Comment: Use a separate branch to keep them so that they are "unrelated" to the long running branch that we are talking about. Say you have a minor-ui-fix branch for this work. What I would do is: fix the problem on the long-running branch, checkout minor-ui-fix, cherry-pick the other branch (that will apply only the last fix related to UI, as we said), then go back to the long running branch and do `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to remove the last ui-related change that you already cherry-picked into the right branch....

Comment: or reset --soft or --mixed if you have stuff laying around that you don't want to clean with --hard, whatever you consider will be right for your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that occurs to me is to have a branch for miscelaneous or minor changes whose purpose is precisely to fix minor things unrelated to the big projects that I am developing on my long-running active branches. For example, for a request for fixing the padding of a link in the footer, instead of applying that minor/trivial change to the long-running branch that I am using, I could apply it to the branch of miscellaneous changes and then that could be merged into "master" regularly. By doing that I could make sure that the names of branches are always intuitive 100% for what the code really does.